# How can I pass a variable to a WHERE clause using mysqli?

Tags: php, binding, parameters, mysqli, where-clause

I currently have a small search form with only two elements: a text input named `search` and a "select" box named `param`. The option selected within that box should be used as a parameter to choose which table column in my DB would be fetched.

Using `mysql_` functions, something like this could be done:

```
$param  = $_POST['param' ];
$search = $_POST['search'];

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE $param LIKE "%$search%"';
```

But I can't get it to work with the `mysqli_` syntax. I am trying to use prepared statements, but the best I've done so far is this:

```
$param  = $_POST['param' ];
$search = $_POST['search'];

if($param == 'first_name')
{
    if($prep = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM table
                               WHERE first_name
                               LIKE CONCAT("%", ?, "%")'))
    {
        $prep->bind_param('s', $search);
        $prep->execute();
        $prep->bind_result($first_name, $last_name);

        while($prep->fetch())
            echo $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;

        $prep->close();
     }
     else
         echo 'Error while preparing statement.';
}
else if($param == 'last_name')
{
    ...
}
```

But just using a bunch of `else if`s seems a lot repetitive and unproductive, specially if I have lots of columns to handle.

The first thing I tried was parameter binding - `... WHERE ? LIKE ...` and `$prep->bind_param('ss', $param, $search)` -, but it didn't work (and I still don't know why).

Is there a way of doing it in a more intelligent way?

Comment: +1 for nice formatting your question

Comment: ....WHERE " . $param . " LIKE.... generally what i do with sql statements

Comment: You can't use placeholders for column names as far as I know, that's why it didn't work.

Comment: change `bind_param('s', $search)` to `bind_param('s', "%$search%")` and the query to  `SELECT * FROM table WHERE first_name LIKE ?` also see user4035's answer how to create an array for valid column names

Comment: @JohnV.: where he used that?

Comment: @Akam "The first thing I tried..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the same SQL code for every param, just create a hash of possible params: `(CGI param name => table column name)`

```
$params = array(
    'first_name' => 'first_name',
    'last_name' => 'last_name',
);
```

It's much better from a security point of view as you are protected from SQL injection.

Then get the column name from the hash and put it into the query - and you'll get rid of the if-s:

```
$name = $params[$param];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
$name LIKE ?";

if($prep = $link->prepare($sql))
{
    $prep->bind_param('s', "%$search%");
    ...
```

As @Akam said, no need to CONCAT("%", ?, "%") in the query - it's better to bind the value with percents right ahead.

Comment: no need to concat in the query, instead: `bind_param('s', "%$search%")`

Comment: @Akam Answer improved

Comment: Effective and clean. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to this example in the PHP manual

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#108790

You seem to be best to add the '%' to the string variable you are binding - rather than in the query e.g. in your example:

```
if($prep = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM table
                           WHERE first_name
                           LIKE ?'))
{
    $search='%'.$search.'%';
    $prep->bind_param('s', $search);
    $prep->execute();
    $prep->bind_result($first_name, $last_name);

    while($prep->fetch())
        echo $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;

    $prep->close();
 }
```

Haven't tested it but it seems like a sensible solution.

Comment: That wont solve his problem of using a dynamic field name, but it will fix his example in his solution to it.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I missed the point. I'd simply substitute the $param string into the query string instead of the column name. I would, however, apply some serious filtering on the content first e.g. $unsafe_col_name="/[^a-zA-Z0-9\\\_]/"; $param=preg_replace("$unsafe_col_name","",$param);

Answer (score 1):

You can't use placeholders for column names, so you'll have to concatenate the column names normally. However, instead of just escaping it with mysqli, because you have a limited set of columns I'd suggest a while list approach:

```
$allowed_params = array('first_name', 'last_name', etc);

$param  = $_POST['param' ];
$search = $_POST['search'];


if(!in_array($param, $allowed_params))
    die("Uh oh, the request seems to have an invalid param!");

if($prep = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM table
                           WHERE ' . $param . '
                           LIKE ?'))
{
    $prep->bind_param('s', '%' . $search . '%');
    $prep->execute();
    $prep->bind_result($first_name, $last_name);

    while($prep->fetch())
        echo $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;

    $prep->close();
}
else
    echo 'Error while preparing statement.';
```

Also note the removal of the `concat` statement, and instead concatenating in PHP. This is important for prepared statements as once it gets to the server it's not actually combining them (thus the protection of prepared statements), so it won't work properly unless the wildcards are sent with the `$search` string.